# how to make wordpress change the title and keep page name?

Tags: theme-development, archives

I want to change the title of my archive page from "category" to "department" to get something like this: Department: Marketing. Where "department" is the archive page title and "Marketing" is the actual name. This is the code that I used:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {

    if( is_category() ) {

        $title = 'department';

    }

    return $title;

});
```

But It hides the page name. When I use this code, I get only "Department" as a title and when I delete it, I get "category: department".

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the actual page title back in.  Try this:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {
    if( is_category() ) {
        $title = 'Department: '. single_cat_title( '', false );
    }
    return $title;
});
```

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly! thanks a lot dear @rudtek

Comment: Great news.  Can you mark it as answered?  (it's the checkmark on the left of the question)